# Set up Google Pay through authorize.net payment provider

Tags: authorize.net, google-pay

In the authorize.net documentation it says:

> To generate a Signature Key for Google Pay:
> Step 1. In the
> Authorize.Net Merchant Interface https://login.authorize.net, navigate
> to Account > Settings > Digital Payment Solutions. The available
> digital payment solutions appear.
> Step 2. In the Google Pay section,
> click Sign Up.
> Step 3. Enter your KeySet ID and generate a Signature
> Key if you haven't yet done so.

But no any information where and how I can get KeySet ID. Can any body help me to find where I can get KeySet ID?

Comment: Also Authorize.Net gateway is missing on the list of the certified Google Pay gateways table https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial#tokenization

Comment: any solution for this one ?

Answer (score 2):

In Sandbox account:

1. Go to 'Account' Tab
2. In the left panel, Click *Digital Payment Solutions*
3. You can SignUp for whichever Mobile Payments Solution you want
4. Enter Key Id and generate the *KeyID*

Comment: I was also trying to integrate the google pay api in authnet. But where we can find the key set id in google pay?